# Magento 2 - How to have a custom "add to cart" button in CMS page?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, cms

So I am trying to add "Add to Cart" button in my CMS page. In one CMS page, I will have one item and multiple "Add to Cart" buttons. I'm wondering how can I do this?

All the existing examples, they user `objectManager` in `.phtml` file which is not a good practice. I'm wondering if there is another way.

This is what I have done so far:
1.) Create a CMS page through the admin panel
2.) Create  `.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/add-to-cart-custom.phtml`
3.) Call the block in CMS page `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::add-to-cart-custom.phtml" product-sku="VVXL10"}}`

I want to pass product-sku and display the buttons using the product-sku, how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a module by following steps:

> 1. app/code/M2Expert/CmsAddtocart/registration.php

with below code:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'M2Expert_CmsAddtocart',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/M2Expert/CmsAddtocart/etc/module.xml

with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="M2Expert_CmsAddtocart" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/M2Expert/CmsAddtocart/Block/CmsCart.php

with below code:

```
<?php
namespace M2Expert\CmsAddtocart\Block;

class CmsCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $productRepository;

    protected $listProductBlock;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getAddToCartUrl()
    {
        if ($_product = $this->getProduct()) {
            return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($_product);
        }

        return '#';
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        if ($product_id = $this->getProductId()) {
            $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($product_id);
            if ($_product) {
                return $_product;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

> 4. app/code/M2Expert/CmsAddtocart/view/frontend/templates/cms/addtocart.phtml

with below code:

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartUrl(); ?>
<?php $buttonText = $block->getButtontext(); ?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <button type="submit"
        title="Add to Cart"
        class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?= ($buttonText)? $buttonText : __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
 </form>
```

**Done!!**

You can now use that on cms page or cms block like below:

```
{{block class='M2Expert\CmsAddtocart\Block\CmsCart' product_id=2 buttontext="Add to
Cart from CMS" template='M2Expert_CmsAddtocart::cms/addtocart.phtml'}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this, also, is there any way to make this button redirect user to cart. I know that we can do that through admin panel, but I don't was that as that will apply to all the "add to cart" buttons in the website. I just want it for this special CMS page.

Comment: then need to create different add action.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still new to Magento, could you please give me an example? Thank you so much.